# Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Angular 8

Tags: angular, heroku, server

After upload angular 8 applications on heroku I get no error in the build but in the console error text.

```
Refused to load the image 'https://MYAPPLICATION.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

MYAPPLICATION.herokuapp.com/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I spent a lot of time trying to solve the problem without success. Help? I read other people's solutions but nothing helped me. How

EDIT EDIT EDIT:

All mesage error

Refused to load the image 'https://MYAPP.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

SOLVED>
Ok i am solved this. 
I have problem with Api Cors from backend but I am using block cors extension which is working in localhost but when is project go to server is not working. I am not have really error message.

Comment: This is to do with the content security policy

Comment: @c_ogoo Ok how to solve problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check adding the following meta tag in index.html?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self';font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https:; style-src 'self' ; script-src 'self'">
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: to improve the quality of the answer, may be worth adding a link to the MDN docs on CSP's and maybe a basic explanation of what  your solution means

Comment: When I opet heroku site i see only blank page with text Not Found and console error?How to explan better ?

Comment: @pichlou This is no work for me :( I find that on any forum but no work for me.. Maybe solution to comeback to old version

Comment: @pichlou after added this meta tag my localost no work. Look my errors
injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js:130 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' ". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. and one more Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

Comment: This will not work. This will conflict with other parts of the application. by example the stylesheet now will not load if you do this